# Dynamically setting height and width of a image view in android Fragment using LayoutParam

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have problem to set the height and width of a image view inside a Fragment activity. I am using the Layout Param. My code is like this

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_details_layout, container, false);
 pdf_image = ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_img));
 pdf_image.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(80, 80));
```

I am getting crash on this code. The logcat is like

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(7517): java.lang.ClassCastException:android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

 E/AndroidRuntime(7517):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1722)

 E/AndroidRuntime(7517):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1667)
 E/AndroidRuntime(7517):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:373)

 E/AndroidRuntime(7517):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to do it:

```
 setContentView(R.id.main);    
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
 ImageView iv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left);
 int width = display.getWidth(); // ((display.getWidth()*20)/100) 
 int height = display.getHeight();// ((display.getHeight()*30)/100)
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new      LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
 iv.setLayoutParams(parms);
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently your parent view is a `RelativeLayout` and you try to use the `LayoutParams` according to it on your `ImageView`. This might cause a `ClassCastException`. Try this instead:

```
 pdf_image = ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_img));
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80,80);
 pdf_image.setLayoutParams(paramImage);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes.It worked. This answer is clear.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use general `LayoutParams`, while you should use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. This is because your layout is apparently a `RelativeLayout`. Try:

```
pdf_image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80));
```

Comment: Yes.It worked. Now i understand the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign width & height as -

```
im.getLayoutParams().width=YOUR_WIDTH;
im.getLayoutParams().height=YOUR_HEIGHT;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
//width & height are your default image 

private void imageLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    imageview = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_imageView);
    height = imageview .getIntrinsicHeight();
    width = imageview .getIntrinsicWidth();
}

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```